# Android retrofit2 with rx sequential requests

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using retrofit2 with Rx. I have two API calls. If first call returns empty response with code 400 I need to make second API call, if not then just to show result. I've implemented custom error handling how shown [here](http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html). Here is my solution:

```
getResponse1(token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new ObserverErrorImpl<Response1, BaseError>(BaseError.class) {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Response1 response) {
                    view.onSuccess(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClientError(BaseError response) {
                    getResponse2(token)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new ObserverErrorImpl<Response2, BaseError>(BaseError.class) {

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Response2 response) {
                                    view.onSuccess(response);
                                    view.hideProgress();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                                    super.onError(throwable);
                                    view.hideProgress();
                                }
                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    super.onError(throwable);
                    view.hideProgress();
                }
            });
```

Is it possible to simplify this code that goes inside method `onClientError`? Is it good solution to like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1).** To simplify it, it would be better that `Response1` and `Response2` will extend some base class, so in your chain, you can operate with base class, which can be casted to certain type when needed

So, let's assume, that you have `BaseResponse`:

```
public abstract class BaseResponse{

    public static int TYPE_RESPONSE_1 = 1;
    public static int TYPE_RESPONSE_2 = 2;

    public abstract int getType();    //every class MUST override this method
}
```

`Response1` and `Response2` should override `BaseResponse`

**2).** `getResponse1` and `getResponse2` should return `Observable<BaseResponse>`

**3).** Your target code:

```
    getResponse1(token)
            .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<BaseResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<BaseResponse> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // I use Retrofit 1.9
                    // And in Retrofit 1.9 I have class RetrofitError, which may provide me all info about error
                    // I'm absolutelly sure Retrofit 2 also have such class,
                    // but it may have another name
                    if(/* is your target error */){
                        //cast it tour target error
                        return getResponse2(token);
                    }
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new ObserverErrorImpl<Response1, BaseError>(BaseError.class) {
                @Override
                public void onNext(BaseResponse response) {
                    if(response.getType() == BaseResponse.TYPE_RESPONSE_1){
                        view.onSuccess(response);
                    } else {
                        view.onSuccess(response);
                        view.hideProgress();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    super.onError(throwable);
                    view.hideProgress();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeesh, why does everyone make it so complicated? In practice I've felt that every time I needed to subscribe to an `Observable` in the `subscribe` of another, there is an operator that will do it much more cleanly for me:

```
 <T,E extends Throwable> Observable<T>
 whenExceptionIs(Class<E> what, Func1<E,Observable<T>> result) {
     return t -> {
        return what.isInstance(t) ? result.call(t) : Observable.error(t);
     };
 }

 getResponse1(token)
 .onErrorResumeNext(whenExceptionIs(BaseError.class, getResponse2(token)))
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 .subscribe(view::onSuccess, view::hideProgress, err -> view.hideProgress());
```

If you have special error handling needs, create a custom `Subscriber` that handles that, but make sure that error handling in general is

- handled in the `Observable` chain if it can do anything about it (ignore it, retry the calls etc)
- propagated downstream.